# To shuffle an array a of n elements C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers, shuffle

I have problem with shuffle array 
The problem is that according to the seed for the random is again the same Result and not 2-exchange and two array is same!
i want 2 result array exchange random

The code is for 2-exchange

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

// A function to generate a random exchange
int* randomized(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Use a different seed value so that we don't get same
    // result each time we run this program

    srand(time(NULL));
    // Start from the last element and swap one by one. We don't
    // need to run for the first element that's why i > 0
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        // Pick a random index from 1 to i-1
        int j = rand() % (i - 1 + 1) + 1;
        //int j = rand() % (i+1);

        // Swap arr[i] with the element at random index
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }

    return arr;
}

// Driver program to test above function.
int main()
{
    int *x1, *x2;
    int arr[] = {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    x1 = randomized(arr, n);
    x2 = randomized(x1, n);
    printArray(x1, n);
    printArray(x2, n);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, `randomized` is in both cases returning the pointer to the same array that's being passed in (`x1` = `x2`). "randomized" sounds like a name for a function that should return a randomized **copy** of the data, not **modify** the original data.

Decide which version you want and based on that, fix either the function or the test program.

Comment: Thanks for answer, changed  x1 = randomized(arr, n);
    x2 = randomized(x1, n);  but the result of X1 and X2 the same!

Comment: @Mohmmad You didn't change anything. `x1` = `x2` = `arr`. If you can't change `main`, make the **copy** of the array, otherwise, make `randomized` return `void` (you don't need pointer you pass in) and `main` would look like this: `randomized(arr, n); printArray(arr, n); randomized(arr, n); printArray(arr, n);`.